# How to dismiss the two or more dismissModalViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dismiss

I need to dismiss the two modal view controllers, I know how to pop two or more view controllers

```
        UINavigationController* navController = self.navigationController;
    NSArray *array=[navController viewControllers];
    UIViewController* controller = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [navController popToViiewController:controller animated:YES];
```

This is how i can navigate back to my first view but if there are two or more dismiss modal view then how can i navigate back

please help me,
Thank you,
Madan Mohan

Comment: To pop to the root view controller you can just do this: `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` instead of your way, which is a bit faffy.

Comment: it is present modal view controllers, how can i pop it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UINavigationController* navController = self.navigationController;
NSArray *viewControllers=[navController viewControllers];
UIViewController* controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[navController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

if you set the object at index 0 in the above code its gonna take you to first view which is a push view controller.

1)Rootview--->moodalview1--->moodalview2--->moodalview3  if you use above code then you wiil be in root view.

2)Rootview--->Pushview1---->moodalview1--->moodalview2----->moodalview3. if you use above code you will be in the PushView.

Answer (score 5):

From the docs for `-[UIViewController dismissModalViewController]`:

> If you present several modal view
>   controllers in succession, and thus
>   build a stack of modal view
>   controllers, calling this method on a
>   view controller lower in the stack
>   dismisses its immediate child view
>   controller and all view controllers
>   above that child on the stack. When
>   this happens, only the top-most view
>   is dismissed in an animated fashion;
>   any intermediate view controllers are
>   simply removed from the stack. The
>   top-most view is dismissed using its
>   modal transition style, which may
>   differ from the styles used by other
>   view controllers lower in the stack.

Answer (score 4):

Use this below code

```
[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController]  dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the following utility static method to simulate popToRootViewController for a stack of modals:

```
// Util.m
+ (void)popModalsToRootFrom:(UIViewController*)aVc {
    if(aVc.parentViewController == nil) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        [Util popModalsToRootFrom:aVc.parentViewController];  // recursive call to this method
        [aVc.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
[Util popModalsToRootFrom:aViewController];
```

If you want something more advanced, you could do this:

```
+ (void)popModalsFrom:(UIViewController*)aVc popCount:(int)count {
    if(aVc.parentViewController == nil || count == 0) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        [Util popModalsFrom:aVc.parentViewController popCount:count-1];  // recursive call to this method
        [aVc.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

Then pass the number of modals to pop, or just -1 to pop all the way to the root.

Answer (score 1):

For `iOS 5`, support of `animation`==`YES` (views will hide in sequence) and `completion` block:

```
+ (void)dismissAllVCsForVC:(UIViewController *)VC animated:(BOOL)animated completion:(BPSimpleBlock)completion {
    if (VC.presentedViewController == nil) {
        if (completion) {
            completion();
        }
    } else {
        [BaseViewController dismissAllVCsForVC:VC.presentedViewController
                                        animated:animated
                                      completion:
         ^{
             [VC dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:completion];
         }];
     }
}
```