# iPhone : How to achieve functionality similar to popToRootViewController using modalView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my app I am `presenting` many view one on the top of another.

So when I want to come out of all the views, I have to press cancel many times.

for example,
HOME->OneViwe(modalView)->SubView(modalView).

How do I directly come to HOME from SubView?

Is there any way to directly come out from all the view?

Or can I dismiss one view after presenting another view? How?

Comment: You can also refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935462/dismiss-modalviewcontroller-from-another-modalviewcontroller/5936872#5936872) post.

Comment: However, if you are popping modalView over modalView, you may want to question your current design modeL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `dismissModalViewContorller` on a view controllers `parentViewController` property. You can use the parentViewController hierarchy until the view controller you want to dismiss completely. If there are three modal view controllers in the hierarchy, your code should look like,

`[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

For a little more flexibility, check out the utility method I use for stuff like this here:

[How to dismiss the two or more dismissModalViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276188/how-to-dismiss-the-two-or-more-dismissmodalviewcontroller/6206226#6206226)